# SQL Nested Calculation JOIN

Tags: oracle, join

There are several dozen threads with this title but none of the ones I found seemed to help.

I have a query composed of two tables: Table Customer and Table Transactions

Each Customer can have multiple entries in the Transactions table. What I want to do is for a given time frame (assume dates are tracked within the Transactions table) take each customer in the Customer table and find three different calculations from the Transactions table for that customer. The first number calculates # of quotes issued, the second calculates the # of orders, and the third is the total number of quotes that didn't turn into an order. The calculations themselves really don't matter as it relates to the solution to this problem.

I feel like there is some type of join I'm not utilizing properly to derive the proper values but here is what I have so far (simplified).

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Count(TransactionAlias1.*), Count(TransactionAlias2.*), Count(TransactionAlias3.*)
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE [...]) TransactionAlias1 ON 
     TransactionAlias1.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE [...]) TransactionAlias2 ON 
     TransactionAlias2.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE [...]) TransactionAlias3 ON 
    TransactionAlias3.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID
```

What's strange to me is having only the first two inner joins produces the correct values for the first two Counts. Adding the third inner join invalidates the other values. Running the select statement within each inner join alone produces the correct count.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If any of you are aware of another StackOverflow article that addresses this same issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be strange - there's surely different WHERE filter in each of the three subqueries, so unless every customer has at least one transaction for each subquery, the inner join will produce the result you don't expect.

You should stay with LEFT JOIN to receive correct results for all customers.
Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT Customer.CustomerID, sum(Count1) as Count1, sum(Count2) as Count2, sum(Count3) as Count3
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT CustomerID,
    case when ... then 1 else 0 end as Count1,
    case when ... then 1 else 0 end as Count2,
    case when ... then 1 else 0 end as Count3
    FROM Transactions
) s Txn
on txn.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customer.CustomerID
```

Comment: I said inner join in my message but I should have said left join. I haven't used inner joins at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the second join should through the counts off.

What about moving the criteria from join conditions to `case` expressions?

```
select Customer.CustomerId
    , count(case when [...] then 1 else null end) as Quote_Count
    , count(case when [...] then 1 else null end) as Order_count
    , count(case when [...] then 1 else null end) as Quote_not_order_count
from Customer
left join Transactions 
    on Transactions.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
```